# Disable overflow of scrollviewer in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I want to disable overflow method of scroll viewer in Windows Phone 8.1.

[Windows Phone scroll viewer](http://www.rodfile.com/8mmjrfqvvtaf)

Please help me to disable this feature in scroll viewer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this effect is inherent to the `ScrollViewer` behaviour and is made by design, so that there is no easy and fast method to do this.

I would recommend you follow the same design guidelines as this will create a consistent user experience.

Comment: How can I make a user control for this? can you help me?